# How to hide input required message "please fill out this field"

Tags: html, css, reactjs, validation

I have added the `required` property to my `input` and I just want to leave the border color without the "please fill out this field" message. Is it possible to hide that message?

```
<input
    placeholder={protocolPlaceholder}
    id="numProtocol"
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
    value={numProtocol}
    required
/>
```

[image]

Comment: you remove required from input filed

Comment: remove `required` attr from `input`

Comment: There is a Russian Stack Overflow, too: https://ru.stackoverflow.com .

Answer (score 4):

It's basically The HTML5 Tooltip that comes along with the `required` attribute, to solve this, try adding an empty form to your DOM, such as:

```
<form id="novalidateform" novalidate />
```

Then add `form="novalidateform"` property to your input:

```
<input
 form="novalidateform"
 placeholder={protocolPlaceholder}
 id="numProtocol"
 onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
 value={numProtocol}
 required
/>
```

Note that the empty form `id` and the prop `form` value given to the input must match.

[More on this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)